# How does NOW() interact with transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions, timestamp

I'm running transactions which perform many updates to one table (taking perhaps a couple of seconds), and then another update to a second table. The final update is timestamped with NOW(): `UPDATE KeyTimestamps SET timestamp=NOW() WHERE key=$key`.

I'm worried about updates happening in one order, but with timestamps that look like they happened in the other order. So that we have the following sequence of table states:

```
key | timestamp
----+--------------------
 A  | 1970-01-01 00:00:00
 B  | 1970-01-01 00:00:00

key | timestamp
----+--------------------
 A  | 2015-12-02 12:00:00
 B  | 1970-01-01 00:00:00

key | timestamp
----+--------------------
 A  | 2015-12-02 12:00:00
 B  | 2015-12-02 11:59:59
```

Can this ever happen? The manual [says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute.

but can one query start to execute before another, and finish executing later? Do transactions protect me against this?

Comment: In general it is possible. You need to be more specific about which thread runs what, to get a more specific answer.

Comment: What would be the alternative? You could generate the value outside of MySQL and pass it as a constant parameter to the UPDATE statement - which, in cases of lock contention, would lead to basically the same problem. The only real alternative would be to eliminate the possibility of contention, so do the statements sequentially without other statements running at the same time.

Comment: Are there alternatives if I don't need it to be a timestamp? E.g. how about a table Monotone with an auto_increment col. In a transaction: many updates; `INSERT INTO Monotone () VALUES ()`; `UPDATE KeyMonotones SET key='A', monotone=LAST_INSERT_ID()`. (Or just one row in Monotone, `UPDATE Monotone SET val=LAST_INSERT_ID(val+1)`.) Would this be safe/are there simpler ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you want to know the ordering of inserts into a table, then use an auto-incrementing column.  This is guaranteed to never have duplicates and should be assigned in insertion order.  You can then compare this ordering to the ordering using a time stamp column.

Note that the time stamp column could be identical for two rows inserted at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

As the manual says, MySQL binds the value of `NOW()` at the start of each individual statement. Therefore, if the value is used multiple times inside a statement, it will be the same.

If you need the value bound at the beginning of a multiple-statement sequence (transaction), do this:

```
SET @start := NOW();
SELECT something;
UPDATE something else;
...
UPDATE KeyTimestamps SET timestamp=@start WHERE key=$key
```

Each distinct client connection will keep its own values of variables like `@start` so this will work when you have multiple clients doing the transactions at once.

**Beware**: operations which you initiate at near-simultaneous times from different clients will run in an order that's formally unpredictable. They won't always run in the order that your intuition tells you they will. So try to avoid depending on the precise order of operations in your system design.  The same is true of autoincrementing ids.  If you do make your system depend on such things, you're creating the possibility of [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  Those are bloody murder to debug.

Comment: You and Gordon Linoff seem to disagree about whether auto-increment columns will always be numbered in insertion order. Do you happen to have a citation that it's unsafe?

Comment: I don't think we disagree. I am sure MySQL will never assign a duplicate autoincrementing id number. And, they'll always be numbered in the order of the insertion. My point is a subtle one about near-real-time operations carried out using anisochronous networks and operating systems. Most of the time your insertions happen in the order your intuition tells you they will, but sometimes they don't. That's because "simultaneous" is a slippery concept. So if you have multiple operations you start within a few milliseconds of one another, the question of which one happens first is slippery.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. So you're saying it'll never (without explicit intervention) show auto-incremented ids 1 and 3, and then later 1, 2 and 3; but if I try to insert A, B and C in that order, it might give me 1-A, 2-C, 3-B?

Comment: Exactly so. order can be slippery.

Comment: I come from the future to inform you the above is false, at least for MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB. Two separate connections both start a transaction. One executes an INSERT, two executes an INSERT. Two commits the transaction. If you now SELECT you will see one record, id = 2. Then one commits its transaction. Now if you select, you will see two records, ids 1 and 2. In this sense, the ids are out of order. When in a transaction, the INSERT will grab an id and increment, even before the transaction is committed. (also if the transaction is rolled back, that number will not be filled)