# Different current_timestamp() when adding data with db.session.add_all() with SQLAlchemy - Not wanted

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, timestamp

Adding rows to a MySQL database with Python. Using the following:

```
db.session.add_all(some_list_with_10K_data)
db.session.commit()
```

In the table there is a column which is defined like this:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
```

Once the table is generated, the time in the `created_at` column is different for every 20 entries, jumping with 1 second for the next one. Any idea how to fix this and have the timestamp for all entries?

I am aware that probably I may write explicitly some value for `created_at` in the list, that is added, but there could be a better solution somewhere. Or not?

Comment: Looks like this is just how MySQL works, it binds CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at the start of each *statement*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041840/how-does-now-interact-with-transactions/34042871#34042871, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: @IljaEverilä - yup, so it looks. However, isn't there a way to "cheat" and somehow force `add_all()` to get one equal timestamp? Or the way to "cheat" is to pass the equal timestamp explicitly in the query?

Comment: From the top of my head I cannot think of a way, other than explicitly passing a common timestamp, but I am not too well versed in MySQL, so might just be missing something obvious.